# 'Enter parameter value' in insert statement

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have 2 tables Project Tracking(pkID as primary) and Status log(pkidStatus as primary and is auto generated and fkidProject, ProjectStatus, StatusDate).
The SurveyRequestIntakeForm has records from ProjectTracking with the pkID field.
The 'Add status Log Entry' button Should run the append query and add a row to the “StatusLog” table – feeding the pkID from the form to the fkProjectid field in the table StatusLog.

```sql
INSERT INTO StatusLog ( fkidProject, ProjectStatus, StatusDate )
SELECT ProjectTracking.pkID, "Start" AS Expr1, Date() AS Expr2
FROM ProjectTracking
WHERE (((ProjectTracking.pkID)=[Forms]![SurveyRequestIntakeForm]![pkID]));
```

When this query runs it shows enter parameter value [Forms]![SurveyRequestIntakeForm]![pkID]

[SurveyRequestIntakeForm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOzKw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
INSERT INTO StatusLog ( fkidProject, ProjectStatus, StatusDate )
VALUES ( [Forms]![SurveyRequestIntakeForm]![pkID] , "Start", Date())
```

Comment: I tried your query but still it shows the Enter parameter value message.

Comment: If you execute the query from code, you must pass the value of `pkID` to the query as a parameter value. Or, simply create the SQL dynamically using the value of `pkID`, and execute that.